# Restlet Connection Timeout

Tags: timeout, restlet

I am using Restlet 2.3.4, and I am trying to implement a timeout mechanism for Restlet Client accessing a server that is not responding.

I tried to select a bunch of different timeout parameters  but without any success. What do I miss ?

```
Context context = new Context();
context.getParameters().add("idleTimeout", "1000");
context.getParameters().add("stopIdleTimeout", "1000");
context.getParameters().add("socketTimeout", "1000");
context.getParameters().add("maxIoIdleTimeMs", "1000");
context.getParameters().add("ioMaxIdleTimeMs", "1000");
client = new Client(context, Protocol.HTTP);
ClientResource service = new ClientResource(DBPEDIA_LOOKUP_SERVICE);
service.setNext(client);
service.setRetryOnError(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this doc https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/snapshot/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/httpclient/HttpClientHelper.html

"idleTimeout" should work

Comment: the link to restlet.com is broken

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the code (I'm using the version 2.3.6) I found out that the parameters are `readTimeout` and `socketConnectTimeoutMs`. In your case, it's the first one.